# How to get foreign key objects with entity framework into a custom object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-5

I am trying to make a select from the database using the `entity framework 5.0`.

I have a table called `Persons` that is referenced by `PersonsImages`, so basically one record from `Persons` can have many `PersonsImages`.

I've made a select statement that gives the Persons, but I would also like to get the PersonsImages as a `List<PersonsImages>`, and put them in a custom object.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
var person = new Persons();

using (var context = new PersonEntities())
{
    person = context.Persons.Where(x => x.personId == 555)
                            .Select(xxx => new Persons
                            {
                                personName = xxx.personName,
                                personLastName = xxx.personLastName,
                                PersonImages = xxx.PersonsImages // there's an error here
                            })
                            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The `Persons` and the `PersonsImages` classes look like that (they are copies of the ones generated by the entity framework):

```
public partial class Persons
{
        public Persons()
        {
            this.PersonsImages = new HashSet<PersonsImages>();
        }

        public string personName { get; set; }
        public string personLastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonsImages> PersonsImages { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonsImages
{
        public string imageName { get; set; }
        public byte[] image { get; set; }
        public virtual Persons Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can make a second select and "manually" find them, but isn't it possible to do it in one, just as what the `entity framework` normally does?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? Did you forget to put the `personId ` property into the `Persons` class in the question? Do you have two `Persons` classes or is it the same class?

Comment: Since you're projecting to the same class, why not try context.Persons.Include(p => p.PersonsImages).FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == 555);

Comment: @YacoubMassad The exception is: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<DataModel.PersonsImages>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyModelClasses.PersonsImages>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes, I have created a local `Persons` class so I can store the results when the DbContext is disposed.

Comment: @SteveGreene That doesn't really help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your error is "can't construct an object in a LINQ to Entities query" - project into an anonymous type, call the `ToArray()` method to enumerate the results, then project into new instances of `Persons`:

```
person = context.Persons.Where(x => x.personId == 555)
                        .Select(xxx => new
                        {
                            personName = xxx.personName,
                            personLastName = xxx.personLastName,
                            PersonImages = xxx.PersonsImages
                        })
                        .ToArray() // data now local
                        .Select(xxx => new Persons
                        {
                            personName = xxx.personName,
                            personLastName = xxx.personLastName,
                            PersonImages = xxx.PersonsImages
                        })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```